# How to disable Model Inconsistency warnings in Minizinc?

Tags: compilation, warnings, minizinc

Some inputs to my Model need to make model inconsistent to result in `Unsatisfiable`. But Minizinc detect these inconsistencies in compile-time and output some warnings. I don't want these warnings. I just want `Unsatisfiable` result in run-time. How to disable them?